# unable to ignore date while calculating time difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

A2 has 6:04:42 PM
B2 has 6:05:02 PM
C2 has 10/23/2015  6:04:38 PM
In D2 I need a formula that finds difference between A2 and C2 (A2-C2) but when I do that I get **#############** because of the date in C2 I believe. I tried changing the format, extracting the timevalue but it is not happening. When I type `=TIMEVALUE(C2)`, it gives me **#VALUE!**

How can I get the exact difference (0:00:04)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display a negative time. That is the reason behind the #########. You will have to remove the date from C2 and subtract the smaller of the two times from the larger.

```
=MAX(MOD(C2, 1), A2)-MIN(MOD(C2, 1), A2)
```

[image: Negative Time]

The raw value of a negative time can also be resolved. By converting that to its absolute value, you will get a time you can display.

```
=ABS(MOD(C2, 1) - A2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In cell D4, enter this formula:

```
=A2-(C2-INT(C2))
```

Apply number formatting of hh:mm:ss

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.